# How to obtain an SSL certificate for Azure Cloud Service

Tags: azure, certificate, ssl-certificate, azure-web-roles

I have an azure cloud service (WebRole) and I want to purchase an SSL certificate.

What is the technical requirements to purchase this certificate?
An SSL provider like godaddy offers 256-bit encryption certificate
but Azure documentation said that **The certificate must use a minimum of 2048-bit encryption**, I no one provide such length.

Comment: Is the following correct:
Asymmetric encryption keys are typically 1024 or 2048 bits, 
but Symmetric key sizes are typically 128 or 256 bits?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

GoDaddy provides certificates that work with Azure just fine.  We use them quiet well (just installed a new one yesterday)

Here's a helpful blog that seems to address the "how-to"
http://blog.amusedia.com/2011/10/setting-up-secure-windows-azure-web.html

Comment: May you provide any guidance for using GoDaddy certificates?

Comment: If you have IIS on your local box you can generate a 2048 bit SSL cert with RapidSSL as outlined http://www.andrewdenhertog.com/tips/creating-adding-ssl-certificates-azure/

Answer (score 5):

All major domain hosting companies support 2048 bit root certificates as shown in this comparison table:

http://www.networksolutions.com/SSL-certificates/compare.jsp

Whoever is hosting your domain/DNS should be able to generate this certificate for you.  I would suggest sending them this link if you aren't sure that they can do it.

http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/enable-ssl/

If the company hosting your domain can NOT issue a SSL/TLS certificate that meets those requirements then you should probably move your domain to someone who can.  I want all of my domain and SSL hosting with only one company for my convenience.

Answer (score 0):

Back in 2013, GoDaddy was an option, but these days Let's Encrypt are offering ***free*** SSL certificates, and there's an Azure Extension that ties in, to auto-renew them, too.

The SSL Certificates from Let's Encrypt are genuine, real and as secure as any other.

Here's a few links to get anyone new to this on their way:

[Let's Encrypt - FAQs](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/faq/)

[SJKP's Azure Site Extension](https://github.com/sjkp/letsencrypt-siteextension/wiki/How-to-install)

[Troy Hunt - Everything you need to know about loading a free Let's Encrypt certificate into an Azure website](https://www.troyhunt.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-loading-a-free-lets-encrypt-certificate-into-an-azure-website/)

[Securing an Azure App Service Website under SSL in minutes with Let's Encrypt](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/SecuringAnAzureAppServiceWebsiteUnderSSLInMinutesWithLetsEncrypt.aspx)